# Is it a good approach to use Hibernate second level cache providers in production environment?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, redis, system-design, second-level-cache

I am trying to understand Hibernate and JPA for the backend microservice application. I got to know by default, Hibernate has first level cache per session. And we can include second level cache providers(example, ehCache) for caching at all-sessions level. But is it a good design approach for production level applications. And on what metrics we must decide to use second level caching? And when to have Reddis/memcache DB for caching ?